# Use Variables as Cases in Select Case

Tags: excel, vba

I have to compare a Variable to other Variables.

Here's a  little Test I've made, which **should** Output; "It's a c"

```
Dim aDim As String: a = "a"
Dim bDim As String: b = "b"
Dim cDim As String: c = "c"
Dim test As String: test = "c"

Select Case test
    Case aDim
        MsgBox "It's an a"
    Case bDim
        MsgBox "It's a b"
    Case cDim
        MsgBox "It's a c"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Something went wrong"
End Select
```

When I start this, I get the "Something went wrong". My tought is that it takes the aDim,bDim and cDim as Strings and not as the Variables with their Values. How can I make it so it takes the Value and not the Name as a string?

Comment: `a` is not declared is should be `aDim`

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module and it will flag your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables you are testing are empty, `aDim` and `a` are different. You declare aDim as string, but it doesnt have any value:

Your code:

```
Dim aDim As String: a = "a"
```

What you probably wanted:

```
Dim aDim As String: aDim = "a"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Had a long day and didn't see that!

Comment: @TheLinkedOne add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. One of the best things you can do here. Or to add it automatically going forward, in the VB Editor, *Tools* > *Options* > *Require Variable Declaration*. It will flag undeclared variables.

Comment: No probs, happens to the best of us ;) As BigBen mentioned it's worth adding Option Explicit to the top of the module! Please remember to mark it as a correct answer if I helped :)

Answer (score 2):

At first glance...

```
Dim a As String: a = "a"
Dim b As String: b = "b"
Dim c As String: c = "c"
Dim test As String: test = "c"

Select Case test
    Case a
        MsgBox "It's an a"
    Case b
        MsgBox "It's a b"
    Case c
        MsgBox "It's a c"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Something went wrong"
End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be

```
Dim aDim As String: aDim = "a"
Dim bDim As String: bDim = "b"
Dim cDim As String: cDim = "c"
Dim test As String: test = "c"

Select Case test
    Case aDim
        MsgBox "It's an a"
    Case bDim
        MsgBox "It's a b"
    Case cDim
        MsgBox "It's a c"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Something went wrong"
End Select
```